What is the voltage across the capacitor and the charge it stores

Assume the switch has been on for a long time. Is it always the case that the voltage across the capacitor = the voltage of the battery? Even though they're in parallel.


Is it always the case that the voltage across the capacitor = the voltage of the battery? Even though they're in parallel.?

It's not "even though they're in parallel," it's because they are in parallel. The voltage across the series combination of $\text{R}_1$ and C must, by Kirchoff's Voltage Law, be equal to the battery voltage at all times when the switch is closed.
Suppose the switch is open, and the voltage across C is not equal to the battery voltage. Then, the switch is closed. At that moment, current will begin to flow through $\text{R}_1$ and C, but that current must exponentially "decay" to zero with time constant equal to $\text{R}_1\text{C}$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant.
After the switch has been closed for "a long time," the current in that branch of the circuit will effectively have decayed to zero, and so by Ohm's Law, the voltage dropped by $\text{R}_1$ must effectively become zero, and so in order to satisfy Kirchoff, the voltage across C by itself must become equal to the battery voltage.

After a long time when transients have died out, in a dc circuit an ideal capacitor will look like an open circuit, meaning there will be no current in the capacitor branch of the circuit. That means the voltage across the capacitor will be the same as the battery voltage which, in turn, is also the voltage across R2. Since there is no current in the capacitor branch there is no voltage drop across R1.
Hope this helps.
